# Adding database column to JComboBox

Tags: java, sql, swing, while-loop, jcombobox

I've searched around for the answer to this, but to no avail. When I compile this, it just returns the last row of my table in the database and not a list of the entire column as I expect. I believe the problem is from here.. If only I can make it list everything in that column, I'd be grateful for your help.

```
String query = "SELECT contact_id, first_name, last_name FROM my_contacts";
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);

while (rs.next())
{
    System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + " " + rs.getString(2) + " " + rs.getString(3));
    String name = rs.getString(2) + " " + rs.getString(3);
        names = new JComboBox();
        names.addItem(rs.getString("first_name"));
}//end while
```

Comment: if you execute that same query in your dbms console you get several rows?
As your code seems to be valid, maybe you are pointing to the wrong schema. Can you verify if your connection properties are set to the db you are looking for?

Comment: the connection properties are well set, and System.out.println(rs.getString(2) + " " + rs.getString(3)); actually returns the entire column as expected, so I wonder why the Combo box does not return the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got everything up and running with this code.

```
        try { 
             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

             Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/recall", "username", "password");

             Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
             String query = "SELECT * FROM names";
             ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);

             while (rs.next())
             {      
                String name = rs.getString("name");         
                names.addItem(rs.getString("name"));
             }//end while
             connection.close();
             } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
             }
```

Answer (score 3):

> When I compile this, it just returns the last row of my table in the
>   database and not a list of the entire column as I expect. I believe
>   the problem is from here..

```
while (rs.next())
{
    System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + " " + rs.getString(2) + " " + rs.getString(3));
    String name = rs.getString(2) + " " + rs.getString(3);
        names = new JComboBox();
        names.addItem(rs.getString("first_name"));
}
```

- your code created a new instance of `JComboBox`, in each of loop inside  `while (rs.next()){`
- create `JComboBox` as local variable, then just to add `Items` in `while-loop` to instance that already exist and is intialized
- best of ways is by using `DeafultComboBoxModel` for `add` / `remove` / `modify` an Items for `JComboBox`